# Pulling the value of a select list and using it to search for an ID value causes all remaining JavaScript to die

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have a form with a drop-down menu, which provides a list of countries. From that, I want that drop-down to show various other remaining form elements depending on what country is selected:

```
<div class="form-group col-sm-6">
  <label class="control-label" for="CountryId">Country</label>
  <select class="form-control" id="CountryId" name="CountryId"><option value="">&#171; ‹ Select › &#187;</option>
    <option value="6793d318-4a5f-430f-8f39-3d4101a7b9c7">Canada</option>
    <option value="4d60e0c3-6e52-4e36-903d-475527b1096b">United States of America</option>
    <option disabled="disabled" value="">--------------------</option>
    <option value="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000">Not Listed, Specify Below:</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div id="address-switcher">
  <div class="address-switch" id="6793d318-4a5f-430f-8f39-3d4101a7b9c7">
    <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
      <label class="control-label" for="ProvinceId">Province</label>
      <select class="form-control" id="ProvinceId" name="ProvinceId"><option value="">&#171; ‹ Select › &#187;</option>
        <option value="9efb1f88-3bb1-405c-9424-6e13d9b07e2f">Alberta</option>
        <option value="5016c6c0-4d8e-442b-a038-c1a70f0839a2">British Columbia</option>
        <option value="7d65582d-5ca5-45f9-9821-9e2d19a8a6a6">Manitoba</option>
        <option value="76d82f69-a381-4365-8938-b198d62844c9">New Brunswick</option>
        <option value="00604e94-ff78-4d59-bdc2-9f3ca5029afd">Newfoundland and Labrador</option>
        <option value="5dec188a-ae59-49f8-add7-9234feb4bc0f">NorthwestTerritories</option>
        <option value="03461d4d-bdaa-4816-8155-80647ab69c83">Nova Scotia</option>
        <option value="3d2be9b8-2241-4884-8ab5-b6243a9dadc8">Nunavut</option>
        <option value="0e37c496-fa7c-449c-b155-afaf7595eda7">Ontario</option>
        <option value="47550c26-a214-429a-a649-7958bc3f7479">Prince Edward Island</option>
        <option value="1f05662e-4bb7-4f5e-9d5f-e061cdf91c34">Quebec</option>
        <option value="34446020-dd4d-4205-bf2d-34a6d413393e">Saskatchewan</option>
        <option value="291363c1-0710-4127-ab47-429f2a18fbe0">Yukon</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
      <label class="control-label" for="PostalCode">Postal Code</label>
      <input class="form-control postalcode text-box single-line" id="PostalCode" maxlength="7" name="PostalCode" type="text" value="" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="address-switch" id="4d60e0c3-6e52-4e36-903d-475527b1096b">
    <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
      <label class="control-label" for="StateId">State</label>
      <select class="form-control" id="StateId" name="StateId"><option value="">&#171; ‹ Select › &#187;</option>
        <option value="22ba78d5-19dc-4672-a20c-1963f56746ac">Alabama</option>
        <option value="9b4ccc2e-e915-4f2e-815a-0ee23cd138ec">Alaska</option>
        <option value="dad82c5b-6b07-4d91-914c-1eb4cc87c6b9">American Samoa</option>
        <option value="a5392b41-f397-473d-9bd9-fc32bd1c1547">Arizona</option>
        <option value="72284a46-6723-4b5c-b45d-9c21a403953e">Arkansas</option>
        <option value="ba55b550-3edd-4b62-bfc1-76ed46847504">California</option>
        <option value="ce60dd97-8810-402e-b235-93eb50603044">Colorado</option>
        <option value="39fd0461-eaee-411f-9b8a-ad887dd91114">Connecticut</option>
        <option value="80832622-2ea4-44f1-b916-8a20e1ed70ee">Delaware</option>
        <option value="7ce45642-6df6-4431-822f-711e97ce3456">District of Columbia</option>
        <option value="f1538bbe-0330-4ffc-b88f-8777dcf09a7a">Florida</option>
        <option value="2aa5b6a8-8f4d-43d4-a1f7-9cb8b3c8b0f5">Georgia</option>
        <option value="da5fbdf5-c77f-475b-ac6e-d1aedc06aeaa">Guam</option>
        <option value="bdeb60fd-ebba-4030-a233-c3ef6b6b605d">Hawaii</option>
        <option value="25bb34c0-a805-48f3-80b7-b968aabbea0e">Idaho</option>
        <option value="cd313f02-0862-489f-ace2-1add4059f974">Illinois</option>
        <option value="44f9ec68-60b0-4bd3-8004-7230f21bacfa">Indiana</option>
        <option value="0989d8da-64bd-44f0-a9a3-4505de785255">Iowa</option>
        <option value="657f0e60-1640-4276-b5a3-5d6d86bfd7c1">Kansas</option>
        <option value="18019d30-db69-4c17-b251-08c8ad21a190">Kentucky</option>
        <option value="eee674df-fdd3-46da-b57c-c5823498431c">Louisiana</option>
        <option value="6cf062dc-3eb4-41eb-b80c-c8f973ac5e1d">Maine</option>
        <option value="bc130b4b-333d-4229-a74c-4888e903fd56">Maryland</option>
        <option value="64e79a3c-276d-4b12-bdce-f2adc892c93c">Massachusetts</option>
        <option value="d0ff1d8a-6ff8-4b20-90c4-083cb55e16a5">Michigan</option>
        <option value="721a4dcc-6900-4fdd-89bd-88265cb9060f">Minnesota</option>
        <option value="2b5d697d-307d-498d-b37e-ae96c56ebf25">Mississippi</option>
        <option value="1dabfd8d-c338-405d-8927-dae85377fa32">Missouri</option>
        <option value="6bef1ad3-430a-42f1-8ae2-87f369c68e47">Montana</option>
        <option value="e220607c-8fc1-4025-ae5b-5aa09398cac9">Nebraska</option>
        <option value="45b7ffe5-b1a2-464a-a714-ed4c4a1e61c2">Nevada</option>
        <option value="4c43f48b-28d1-4366-9167-b6ca09403ba0">New Hampshire</option>
        <option value="655e1cfc-5bae-4044-9c9f-c6d6e5e87db7">New Jersey</option>
        <option value="a690c066-47dd-497a-a7ca-f49bdd78b6b0">New Mexico</option>
        <option value="dbf065d5-e5dd-4d38-b70c-4cc54df13b12">New York</option>
        <option value="bf0d8aa6-b22e-424e-a68d-efbca31847cf">North Carolina</option>
        <option value="794e2fed-bea2-4dd9-8b43-e04d382ae737">North Dakota</option>
        <option value="33564f9f-8c87-4316-967d-9a281bfdf632">Northern Mariana Islands</option>
        <option value="3e40c5ce-8584-4b35-bda8-0feaabed30e3">Ohio</option>
        <option value="4d4d6162-61a6-4d6d-833d-582436656ec5">Oklahoma</option>
        <option value="5e08c48a-8620-4298-87aa-c231ee62b3fc">Oregon</option>
        <option value="f428f11f-63e3-494b-93ba-cd530f269338">Pennsylvania</option>
        <option value="2933e363-ae18-427d-9162-d0971dd5530b">Puerto Rico</option>
        <option value="b690c1d4-3614-4df4-92e7-b23f92baaa6f">Rhode Island</option>
        <option value="d7b739b9-b46f-47c1-83c9-9c96133953b0">South Carolina</option>
        <option value="a6a797f0-a2dd-4e37-949d-bb455d72c5ad">South Dakota</option>
        <option value="3c5583dc-7e14-49e3-996e-ea9d42858fb6">Tennessee</option>
        <option value="f1712b25-a54c-4ad1-81cd-c59005ee5178">Texas</option>
        <option value="26ecd50b-a3e5-48f7-9659-c116e0782e4a">U.S. Virgin Islands</option>
        <option value="540d971e-ae86-40ed-93b0-34f40435f332">Utah</option>
        <option value="da2393c5-050e-4d2e-a82c-ff6469c15432">Vermont</option>
        <option value="4ddb4a88-15c8-4e92-ac75-4619d59186f4">Virginia</option>
        <option value="b8b1d38c-17f2-4eaa-b792-4d52c47eae92">Washington</option>
        <option value="21f91d65-a89c-4d0a-b746-ed39d0ac6948">West Virginia</option>
        <option value="4d0d0315-1b41-4bb2-94bc-1fd4a3633b0a">Wisconsin</option>
        <option value="a2996f17-e126-4853-b265-dd09976646c1">Wyoming</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
      <label class="control-label" for="ZipCode">Zip Code</label>
      <input class="form-control zipcode text-box single-line" id="ZipCode" maxlength="10" name="ZipCode" type="text" value="" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="address-switch" id="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000">
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
      <label class="control-label" for="CountryName">Country</label>
      <input class="form-control text-box single-line" id="CountryName" maxlength="64" name="CountryName" type="text" value="" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
      <label class="control-label" for="ProvinceName">Province</label>
      <input class="form-control text-box single-line" id="ProvinceName" maxlength="64" name="ProvinceName" type="text" value="" />
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
      <label class="control-label" for="Postal">Postal Code</label>
      <input class="form-control text-box single-line" id="Postal" maxlength="10" name="Postal" type="text" value="" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

On a blank form, the selection of the drop-down is supposed to hide/unhide the relevant parts: Selecting US gets a State drop-down and a ZipCode text field. Selecting Canada gets a Province drop-down and a PostalCode text field. Etc., etc.. I have used the following JS to achieve this effect:

```
$('#address-switcher').children('.address-switch').addClass('hidden');
$('#CountryId').change(function () {
  $('#address-switcher').children('.address-switch').addClass('hidden');
  $('#address-switcher').children('#' + this.value).removeClass('hidden');
});
```

On a pre-filled form, selecting the drop-down does exactly the same thing, but I have an additional requirement: because a country will have already been selected, I need to automatically un-hide the correct form fields for that country. As in, if an address was already in Canada, I need the Province drop-down and PostalCode form field to be un-hidden automatically, by default. I need to be able to have JS look at the SelectList, see that "Canada" is `selected="selected"`, and un-hide the `div` whose `id` matches that of the `value` of the Canada `option`.

To this end, I have created an “auto-unhider” (to be in the second line of the JS block above, right after the JS that hides everything upon page load):

```
$('#address-switcher').children('#' + $('#CountryId').val()).removeClass('hidden');
```

Which works beautifully, ***but only for a form that has been pre-filled from the database!!***

Problem is, all attempts to add this auto-unhiding-upon-filled-form-load is causing any blank form to fail. As in, the "unhider" script is failing for the empty form when the "auto-unhider" portion is present. The unhider script still works for the filled form, just not for the blank form. Comment the "auto-unhider" out, and poof -- the blank forms work again, but filled forms don’t auto-unhide anymore.

I have tried any number of ways to “sanitize” the auto-unhider so that it only fires when a filled form has been loaded, but all attempts have failed:

```
if ($('#CountryId option:selected').length !== 0) {
  $('#address-switcher').children('#' + $('#CountryId').val()).removeClass('hidden');
}
```

.

```
if (typeof $('#CountryId').val() !== "undefined") {
  $('#address-switcher').children('#' + $('#CountryId').val()).removeClass('hidden');
}
```

.

```
if (typeof $('#CountryId option:selected') !== "undefined") {
  $('#address-switcher').children('#' + $('#CountryId').val()).removeClass('hidden');
}
```

In each and every case, I have confirmed that this “sanitization” has failed for a blank form because commenting out the auto-unhider (without touching the sanitization `if`) causes a blank form to work again.

I need an auto-unhider that doesn’t affect the unhider script for blank forms, or a sanitizing `if` *that will actually do its job* of preventing its contents from firing on a blank form. I need to find a way to isolate or sanitize the auto-unhider script so that it never has the opportunity to fire for a blank form, but does fire where the Country SelectList has an actual selected option (form reload after validation failure or form filled from DB).

Comment: `$('#CountryId').find(':selected').val()` should be simply `$('#CountryId').val()` and `$('#address-switcher').children('#' + $(this).val())` should be simply `$('#' + this.value)`

Comment: If all other scripts break, that suggests you've got an exception in there (probably a syntax error, as jQuery usually doesn't throw but just does nothing). Check your console.

Comment: @Bergi unfortunately your first suggestion did not work. And the console is clear of all errors.

Comment: @Bergi Actually, you were correct. I stand corrected. However what I found through Google (overwhelmingly so) also contradicts what actually works -- strange, that.

Comment: If you found a solution, you might [want to post it as an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: Actually, I still have a problem. Solution works on pages with forms that pre-fill, it fails on forms that are blank upon load.

Comment: Check typeof === 'undefined' before you use potentially not existing objects / elements.

Comment: @Lemmy Sorry, `typeof` fails to isolate the required JS from blank forms.

Comment: $('#address-switcher').children('#' + $('#CountryId')    AND     $('#address-switcher')
Could also be undefined ...

Comment: No, that content is manually hard-coded into the page. That content exists on multiple pages regardless of what content the form is loaded up with.

Comment: Please edit your question into a cohesive whole. I'd try, but my eyes glaze over after the first screenful of text. Also look into how to create a [mcve].

Comment: Just put a check around, it will not harm you ....

Comment: I suggest to rewrite the code without chaining, normal vars and functions if required, put some break points and debug it. Writing code like that may look fancy but it's is hard to debug and maintain. In a weeks time you will try to remember what this code did.

Comment: Rewrote the entire original post. Removed all edits. Should be cohesive now.

Comment: Solved it. Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I discovered has been… *interesting*… to employ a massive understatement.

To put it bluntly: my own personal assessment that JavaScript is the Devil’s programming language, meant explicitly to drive us insane, has just been upheld.

Turns out that **there is no way to confirm if a SelectList does *not* have a selected item**, because… *drum roll* …the *visible entry* even on a *blank and empty form*, which (incidentally) is *prior* to any human interaction, *counts as the “selected item”*.

Whisky. Tango. Foxtrot.

My discovery of a solution was fortunate due to two significant attributes of how I built the form:

1. On a form (using the HTML above, in my OP) that is pre-filled from the database, I have the Country SelectList set up to *not* have a “choose one” entry at the very top. Because content is being drawn from the DB, there is no need to have one, and actually a desire to
   *not* have one as a selectable item, because the business logic has a country as a required item for a user profile. They *need* to have either “Canada”, “United States” or “None of the above” (which then triggers the manual country and province text fields), so *every `value`* of the SelectList actually has content. Or essentially, something more than an empty string.
2. On a form that is empty upon load, the Country SelectList *does* have a “choose one” entry at the top of its list, so as to **not** automatically un-hide a set of form fields that may not be appropriate for the user, and to force them to explicitly choose a country (the business logic forbids a null value for that DB field). This item may have a `value=""` (a zero length string), but *it does have a value* even though it is a string of zero length.

What I needed to look for was *not* a SelectList that had no selected item, but a select list *where the selected item had no content for its value*.

Again: Whisky. Tango. Foxtrot.

Because an empty form on page load will have the “Select One” item visible, ***that entry is the “officially selected” item!!*** It was impossible, from the start, to actually check to see if the SelectList had a selected item or not, because *it always had one even when the form was empty*. As in, ***an unselected SelectList is an impossibility.*** All SelectLists have a selected state, even when completely empty and untouched by the user.

All together, now: Whisky. Tango. Foxtrot.

In the end, my solution (which actually works across both Chrome and Firefox, thank goodness) is thus:

```
if (typeof $('#CountryId').val() !== 'undefined') {
  $('#address-switcher').children('.address-switch').addClass('hidden');
  if ($('#CountryId').val() !== '') {
    $('#address-switcher').children('#' + $('#CountryId').val()).removeClass('hidden');
  }
  $('#CountryId').change(function () {
    $('#address-switcher').children('.address-switch').addClass('hidden');
    $('#address-switcher').children('#' + this.value).removeClass('hidden');
  });
}
```

Notice how I explicitly check the SelectList to see if the currently selected value is *not* an empty string?:

```
if ($('#CountryId').val() !== '') {
```

That is what made all the difference.

I added the root `if (typeof …){}` so the script wouldn’t fire on each and every page, seeing as it’s required on several pages and therefore exists in the common js that is on every page.